# VueJS Input field value not binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with my generic input fields. 
In other words I've made a generic input field which should cover regular input fields, checkboxes and radiobuttons. But when I try to pass a string value as a value of the radio input field, the prop is empty.

```js
<TextInput
        v-model="name"
        description="Name & LastName"
        name="Name & Surname"
        rules="required"
      />
      <TextInput
        v-model="age"
        type="number"
        description="Age"
        name="Age"
        rules="required|digits:2"
      />
      <div id="gender-fields">
        <legend>Please specify your gender:</legend>
        <TextInput
          v-model="gender"
          type="radio"
          description="Male"
          name="Gender"
          rules="required"
        />
        <TextInput
          v-model="gender"
          type="radio"
          description="Female"
          name="Gender"
          rules="required"
        />
        <TextInput
          v-model="gender"
          type="radio"
          description="Unspecified"
          name="Gender"
          rules="required"
        />
      </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

This is how I'm declaring my input fields in my form.
Here's the definiton of the Input Field.

```js
<template>
  <ValidationProvider
    tag="div"
    :rules="rules"
    :name="name"
    :vid="vid"
    v-slot="{ errors }"
    :mode="mode"
  >
    <label>
      {{ description }}
      <input :type="type" v-model="currentValue" :value="value" />
    </label>
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";
export default {
  name: "TextInput",
  components: {
    ValidationProvider
  },
  props: {
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    value: {
      required: true
    },
    rules: {
      type: [String, Object],
      default: ""
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    vid: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text"
    },
    mode: {
      type: String,
      default: "aggressive"
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentValue: ""
  }),
  watch: {
    currentValue(val) {
      // allows us to use v-model on our input.
      this.$emit("input", val);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

THe only input fields I have a problem with are those radio buttons. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I forgot to add the value="male" into a <TextInput> component when posting the example. It doesn't work even when passed in.

Comment: You're binding both `v-model` and `value` on the native input.  This is a problem because `v-model` is just a special way of  binding `value`.  On a normal textbox, you get this error:  `:value="value" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to skip putting `:value="value"` on the input and change your watch like this:

```
  watch: {
    //watch for value to change and assign it to our currentValue
    value: {
      handler(val) {
        this.currentValue = val;
      },
      //this makes it run the handler function on mount in addition to whenever the value changes
      immediate:true
    },
    currentValue(val) {
      // allows us to use v-model on our input.
      this.$emit("input", val);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ryley, I was having the same issue and it fixed it.  I'm interested to know why this isn't done in the same that it looks like Milan and I both used, do you know if this could be due to some recent change?  I can't for the life of me find the original source that I used, although I know I changed my implementation up a bit from what I was using, so wasn't sure if I'd broken it in the process.