# Two-way binding with input value transform

Tags: vue.js, v-model, two-way-binding

As the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html) states, `v-model` directive on `input` element provides syntax sugar for a combination of bound `value` prop and `input` event handler.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760974/vue-3-pattern-for-input), an input fails to synchronize with bound value when used with `input` event handler that transforms a value:

```js
new Vue({
  template: '<input :value="val" @input="onUpdate" />',
  data: () => ({ val: '' }),
  methods: {
    onUpdate(e) {
      this.val = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
      console.log('val', this.val);
    }
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

A demo:

> [image: demo]

The same input works as intended when used with `v-model` and a watcher, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996077/3731501):

```js
new Vue({
  template: '<input :value="val" @input="onUpdate" />',
  data: () => ({ val: '' }),
  methods: {
    onUpdate(e) {
      this.val = e.target.value;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    val: {
      handler(val) {
        this.val = val.replace(/\s/g, "");
        console.log('val', this.val);
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Doing this in the same handler also fixes the problem:

```
    onUpdate(e) {
      this.val = e.target.value;
      this.val = this.val.replace(/\s/g, "");
    }
```

What does happen here? Why does the direct assignment of transformed value to `val` doesn't work, but doing this in two steps does?

This problem applies to both Vue 2 and 3.

Comment: I am able to achieve the combination of (value and input event) in the input and it is working fine for me. I added my answer on same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761487/4116300 .. this is what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same case, but it's buggy, you can see that in demo video

Comment: You mean, its updating the values on next key press instead of immediate update .. Right ?

Comment: Depending on what's entered, yes

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but this is my understanding of what's going on:

With the @input/value pair, if you change the value to be **what the value was already**, reactivity won't trigger, and so won't change the value in the input.

With v-model, the value will be changed to the new value, (including the space). This will trigger reactivity. Then the watcher will change it back. And when the DOM finally updates, it will set the value of the input.

Using `this.val = e.target.value; this.val = this.val.replace(/\s/g, "");` works because you've triggered the reactivity with the first statement.

However, when you use `@input`, nothing yet has changed the `val`, and when you set it to remove spaces from the input's `target.value`, you're setting it to what `val` was already, and reactivity won't trigger.

It's also worth noting that v-model is only real syntactic sugar when used on a component. When used on a native input, it's not exactly the same. See [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9299#issuecomment-478557149) issue for example.